# Для класса не существует конструктор по умолчанию

Tags: c++, классы, virtual, множественное-наследование

Возникла следующая проблема, нужно задать классам и функциям виртуальные классы, чтобы не было переопределения и в общем возникаем ошибка, которая описана в названии. Да, и еще это множественное наследование, если не трудно, то подскажите, всё ли работает как нужно, если задание такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class B {
    int a;
public:
    B() { };
    B(int x) { a = x; }
    virtual void show_B() { cout << "B=   " << a << "\n"; }
};

class D1 : virtual public  B {
    int b;
public:
    D1(int x, int y) : B(y) { b = x; };
     void show_D1() { cout << "D1=  " << b << "\n"; show_B(); }
};

class D2 : protected B {
    int c;
public:
    D2(int x, int y) : B(y) { c = x; };
    void show_D2() { cout << "D2=  " << c << "\n"; show_B(); }
};

class D3 : virtual public D2 {
    int d;
public:

    D3(int x, int y,int z, int i) : D2(y,z) { d = x; }
    void show_D3() { cout << "D3=  " << d << "\n"; show_D2(); }
};

class D4 :protected D1, private D3 {
    int e;
public:
    D4(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j, int u, int k) : D1(y, z), D3(i, j, u, k) { e = x; }
    void show_D4() { cout << "D4=  " << e << "\n"; show_D1(); show_D3(); }
};


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    D4 temp1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7);

    cout << "D4 temp1(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);\n";
    cout << "\nСледуя иерархии класса D4\n";
    temp1.show_D4();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибку выбивает в данной строке кода `D4(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j, int u, int k) : D1(y, z), D3(i, j, u, k) { e = x; }`
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, по вашему рисунку иерархия должна строится так:

```
class B {
int a;
public:
    //любой конструктор должен инициализировать все члены, дабы сохранить инвариант
    B():a(0) { };
    B(int x) { a = x; }
    virtual void show_B() { cout << "B=   " << a << "\n"; }
};

class D1 : virtual public  B {
    int b;
public:
    D1(int x, int y) : B(y) { b = x; };
    void show_D1() { cout << "D1=  " << b << "\n"; show_B(); }
};

//по указанной схеме D2 и D1 должны наследовать один и тот же объект
class D2 : virtual protected B {
    int c;
public:
    D2(int x, int y) : B(y) { c = x; };
    void show_D2() { cout << "D2=  " << c << "\n"; show_B(); }
};

//тут нет требований иметь виртуального наследования
//(нет нужды наследовать один и тот же объект)
class D3 :  public D2 {
    int d;
public:

    D3(int x, int y, int z, int i) : D2(y, z) { d = x; }
    void show_D3() { cout << "D3=  " << d << "\n"; show_D2(); }
};

class D4 :protected D1, private D3 {
    int e;
public:
    D4(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j, int u, int k) : D1(y, z), D3(i, j, u, k) { e = x; }
    void show_D4() { cout << "D4=  " << e << "\n"; show_D1(); show_D3(); }
};
```

Тогда, с вызовом конструкторов не будет проблем, так как все наследуют один конкретный  объект базового класса, а он имеет конструктор по умолчанию.

Так, как вы сделали, для конструирования объекта `temp1` нужно конструировать  `D1`  и `D3`, а  последный имеет `виртуальный базовый класс D2`, а это значит, что любой целевой класс должен его конструировать, так как объект является один и тот же, но  конструктор класса `D4` **не инициализирует** `D2`, поэтому вызывается **его(`D2`) конструктор  по умолчанию**, которого просто нет(вы не написали)... И не забывайте, что любой конструктор должен инициализировать члены класса, если они не инициализированы. Сохраняйте инвариант(свойство объекта иметь определенное состояние) **всегда**!!!

Comment: Если вам не трудно, то еще ответьте на один вопрос. Когда мы запускаем программу, то для B вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, а соответственно задается значение 0. Как сделать так, чтобы вызывался конструктор с параметрами и B задавалось значение последнего этапа цепочки https://ibb.co/JC2Bk7k

Comment: Я отсутствовал, но надеюсь теперь не поздно:   в инициализаторе конструктора, в таком случаи, нужно указывать как должен конструироваться базовый класс, т. е. добавить, например,   `B(k)` к списку

Comment: Не получается из-за того, что по сути нужно будет в D4 вызвать два раза B(z) и B(k), потому что он в цепочке отображается два раза, вот так, как я понял:
D4(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j, int u, int k) : D1(y, z),B(z),D3(i,j,u,k),B(k) { e = x; }. Но все равно спасибо огромное вам за помощь.

Comment: по этому поводу можете задать новый вопрос..